# Spark: What happens if my partition size is bigger than the executor size?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have read that the executor's execution and storage memory should be at least as big as the largest partition of data, or else I will get OOM errors. However, this doesn't seem to be the case for my PySpark code. I'm currently running only one executor with 2 cores and 500+384 MiB memory. I have adaptive and dynamicAllocation turned off

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.\
config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled",False).\
config("spark.executor.cores","2").\
config("spark.executor.instances","1").\
config("spark.executor.memory","500m").\
config("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", False).\
config("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes","13g").\
getOrCreate()
```

My data description is as follows:

- I have a CSV that is 13GiB on disk.
- It gets read in 2 partitions that are each around 1000 MiB (1001.9 MiB, 963 MiB) in Serialized form.

Each partition is way over the executor's allocated execution+storage memory. Despite this, I am able to run the following code successfully:

```py
df_covid = spark.read.csv("gs://xxxxxxxx.appspot.com/spark_datasets/covid13g.csv",
                          header=True, inferSchema=False)
df_covid.cache()
df_covid = df_covid.withColumn("_catted", F.concat_ws('',*df_covid.columns))

df_covid = df_covid.filter(F.length(df_covid._catted) > 20)

df_covid.count()
```

Why is this the case?

I think the entire stage applies all the tasks row by row and the entire partition is not be read before the transformations are to be applied. I can see this behavior in the spark sql web UI

[image: 16 mil read 16 mil processed]

16 mil read 16 mil processed

[image: .9 mil read .9 mil processed]
.9 mil read .9 mil processed

Comment: I understand this might be a silly question. But, if you are downvoting can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: It is a great question. Does it still work with only one core in the executor ?

Comment: Also do you see spill yo disk in the spark ui on the executor panel ?

Comment: Thank you for your interest parisni :). Yes. It works perfectly fine with just one core as well. I do not see any spills

Comment: There are spills if I remove the caching

Comment: I do not think spark first reads a partition and then applies the transformations to it. Reading the dataset is part of the stage and all the tasks are fused together via codegen and that entire thing applies row by row. I have updated the question with a few screenshots to support this

Comment: yes likely for filter operation spark won't store the whole partition in memory. If you do sort or drop duplicate, then you might get trouble

Comment: Hopeless understanding the output in some cases.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "hopeless understanding the output in some cases". Explain further. Question, as is mentioned above is "why is this the case?". Which, given the context of the question, unambiguously means "why is that the executors are not throwing OOM errors"?

Comment: Did you supply anything for the `--master` argument? Could you just verify in the Environment tab which `spark.master` value you're running with?